# How to route to a PDF file in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, hyperlink

I'm trying to redirect to the PDF on route:

```
{ path: 'regulations', redirectTo: '/regulations/Regulations_10.02.2021.pdf' }
```

But it doesn't work. Previously I used a normal link like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="regulations/Regulations_10.02.2021.pdf">Regulations</a>
```

But in a situation where the regulations are updated, the link will change.

Not sure if Routing is the way to go either, I have only learned to route components based on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd need to use Angular router in this case. You could continue to use `<a>` anchor tag and bind a dynamic `href` property to it.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class SomeComponent {
  regulationsFile: string;

  someFunction() {      // <-- illustration
    this.regulationsFile = 'Regulations_10.02.2021';
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<a target="_blank" [href]="'regulations/' + regulationsFile + '.pdf'">Regulations</a>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I want to link always be "/regulations" and redirect to actual regulations document. In your example link will change when the regulations change.
Because, for example, I add regulations link to emails, and I want my old emails to have relevant links.